# Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: DuplicateRecordItem

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

i am writing a trigger on account object on after delete event .

scenario:

once Account records are merged the trigger should delete corresponding Duplicate Record Set record.

code:

```
public static void deleteDRS(List<Account> accountList){


List<DuplicateRecordItem> dupRecs = [SELECT Id,RecordId,DuplicateRecordSetId FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE RecordId in: accountList];

system.debug('dupRecs'+ dupRecs);

Set<Id> dupRecSet = new Set<Id>();
 for(DuplicateRecordItem dupItem : dupRecs){
dupRecSet.add(dupItem.DuplicateRecordSetId);
}

 List<DuplicateRecordSet> dupRecSetList = [SELECT Id FROM DuplicateRecordSet WHERE Id in: dupRecSet];

  if(dupRecSetList.size() > 0){

     delete dupRecSetList;
  }
}
```

but i am getting following error ****strong text**Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: DuplicateRecordItem**

can some one help me .

Comment: what is DuplicateRecordItem?

Comment: There is nothing here that could cause a compilation error. Do any other class files have an incorrect reference to `DuplicateRecordItem` that you are deploying?

Comment: @NickCook FYI https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecorditem.htm.

Comment: How are you merging the account records?

Comment: is Duplicate Management enabled in the org? what version is the class?